# How to detect if front camera is active

Tags: ios, swift

I have a uibutton to activate and inactivate flash.  I need to hide the button when I change camera to front as it doesn't have a flash in front . And, need to unhide when I change the cam to back again. Appreciate your help.

```
 @IBAction func changeCamera(sender: AnyObject) {

    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, {

        let currentVideoDevice:AVCaptureDevice = self.videoDeviceInput!.device
        let currentPosition: AVCaptureDevicePosition = currentVideoDevice.position
        var preferredPosition: AVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Unspecified

        switch currentPosition{
        case AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front:
            preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back

        case AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back:
            preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front

        case AVCaptureDevicePosition.Unspecified:
            preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back

        }


        let device:AVCaptureDevice = takePhotoScreen.deviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferringPosition: preferredPosition)

        var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

        do {
            videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        } catch _ as NSError {
            videoDeviceInput = nil
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }


        self.session!.beginConfiguration()

        self.session!.removeInput(self.videoDeviceInput)

        if self.session!.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput){

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification, object:currentVideoDevice)

            takePhotoScreen.setFlashMode(AVCaptureFlashMode.Auto, device: device)

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "subjectAreaDidChange:", name: AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChangeNotification, object: device)

            self.session!.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
            self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

        }else{
            self.session!.addInput(self.videoDeviceInput)
        }

        self.session!.commitConfiguration()



        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.snapButton.enabled = true
            self.cameraButton.enabled = true

        })

    })

}


@IBAction func toggleTorch(sender: AnyObject) {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.On) {
                device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.Off
            } else {
                do {
                    try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your hide unhide code here

```
 switch currentPosition{
    case AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front:{
           preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back;
         // UNHIDE FLASH BUTTON HERE
           break;
         }

    case AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back:{
            preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front
         // HIDE FLASH BUTTON HERE
           break;
         }

    case AVCaptureDevicePosition.Unspecified:
        preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back

    }
```

P.S - I dont know swift syntax properly, but this should point you to the right direction. Also use break whenever you use switch. Dont know if its needed in swift 2.0, but still its good practice.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a quick note, when I switch camera, it takes around 5 seconds to hide or unhide button. So I used following way to  make it quick : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.torchButton.hidden = false
                    })

Comment: yeah its cool, as i dont know in which thread your code is running, so putting your UI code inside the main thread is a pretty good idea.